Docker user openfoam cannot create file or directory in shared host folder
I am running Docker on Ubuntu and have created a shared folder /public
The access rights are
19267585 4,0K drwxrwxrwx  5 jens docker 4,0K abr 12 15:01 .
with jens being my user on the host system. The folder is shared via Docker desctop and available within the container as /tmp.
When logging into the Docker container as root I can create a file, e.g.
(base) jens@sat:/public/case/0$ docker exec -ti -u root agitated_knuth bash
root@92222f888a3f:~# cd /tmp
root@92222f888a3f:/tmp# touch test.txt
root@92222f888a3f:/tmp# ls -lisah .
total 20K
19267585 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 5 root nogroup 4.0K Apr 12 13:05 .
 1346379 4.0K drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4.0K Apr 12 12:16 ..
19267588 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 5 root root    4.0K Apr 12 12:55 case
19267617 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 9 root root    4.0K Apr 12 12:55 meshCase
19267726    0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Apr 12 13:05 test.txt
19267725 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    4.0K Apr 12 13:01 tutorials

When logging in as openfoam user, I cannot create any files or folders there, even though I added the user to the group root:
(base) jens@sat:/public$ docker exec -ti -u openfoam agitated_knuth bash
openfoam@92222f888a3f:~$ cd /tmp
openfoam@92222f888a3f:/tmp$ touch test2.txt
touch: setting times of 'test2.txt': No such file or directory
openfoam@92222f888a3f:/tmp$ cp -r /opt/openfoam10/tutorials/ .
cp: cannot create regular file './tutorials/Allclean': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create regular file './tutorials/Allrun': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create regular file './tutorials/Alltest': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/DNS': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/basic': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/combustion': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/compressible': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/discreteMethods': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/electromagnetics': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/financial': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/heatTransfer': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/incompressible': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/lagrangian': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/mesh': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/multiphase': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/resources': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create directory './tutorials/stressAnalysis': Invalid argument
openfoam@92222f888a3f:/tmp$ ls -lisah .
total 24K
19267585 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 6 root nogroup 4.0K Apr 12 13:22 .
 1346379 4.0K drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4.0K Apr 12 12:16 ..
19267588 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 5 root root    4.0K Apr 12 12:55 case
19267617 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 9 root root    4.0K Apr 12 12:55 meshCase
19267728 4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2 root root    4.0K Apr 12 13:07 shared
19267726    0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Apr 12 13:05 test.txt
19267725 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    4.0K Apr 12 13:01 tutorials


I am using the docker image from mmcker/cfdof-openfoam, in case it matters.
I don´t understand, why the openfoam user is not able to write, e.g. files in the tutorials subfolder (access 777) or make a single test file.
